# Request.UrlReferrer is returning "null" in Internet Explorer 7, 8, 9 browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

Request.UrlReferrer of C# is returning null in case of Internet Explorer 7, 8, 9 browsers. What is the reason of it? What is the solution of it?

There are some "Click Here" buttons on a page(s). On clicking the button, a new url page is opened in new tab. At the time of opening the page, I am storing the Page's url in the database using Request.UrlReferrer.

For other browsers like Firefox, Chrome etc, it is working fine. But it has never worked on Internet Explorer.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

The referrer can be empty in a variety of cases. For example some privacy settings (forcale by policy) or plugins can prevent the referrer to be sent. It is in any way user input, something which you cannot trust.

If you explain what you are trying to do and what code you use to do so, perhaps an actual answer can be given.

Comment: There are some "Click Here" buttons on a page(s). On clicking the button, a new url page is opened in new tab. At the time of opening the page, I am storing the Page's url in the database using Request.UrlReferrer.

Comment: Then just add a parameter to the new page's URL, like `&from=pageX`. It's as unreliable as the referrer (as users can change it), but at least you can control that it gets sent regardless of browser configuration

Comment: What if I cannot pass any parameter? What can be the other way?

Comment: There will be a way, but please edit your question to include full details of what you want to do, what your relevant code looks like and what changed that made it stop working.

Comment: For other browsers like Firefox, Chrome etc, it is working fine. But it has never worked on Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

When opening a new window with `document.location.href` or `window.open` in IE8 or lower, `Request.UrlReferrer` is `null` which is not the case in IE9+, Firefox or Chrome.

The solution is, where ever you used like

```
document.location.href = "/Roles/Index";
```

Just copy and paste the below function in js file and call that function.

```
RedirectURL("/Roles/Index");

function RedirectURL(url) {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  if (a.click) {
    // HTML5 browsers and IE support click() on , early FF does not.
    a.setAttribute("href", url);
    a.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
  } else {
    // Early FF can, however, use this usual method
    // where IE cannot with secure links.
    window.location.href = url;
  }
}
```

Hopefully the above solution will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use window.open(targetUrl, "_blank") function to open a page in a new browser tab, UrlReferrer is null for IE - actually for me this problem is reproducible even for IE 11 but not only for old versions of IE.
The following JavaScript code allowed me to resolve the problem:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = targetUrl;
link.target = "_about";
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

I know that the question is old. But maybe my answer will help someone.